# Sql Update Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table `T1` which contains three columns: `Id, Name, Address`

There is another table `T2` which contains 2 columns `Id, New_Address`. `Id` column of `T2` is same as of `T1`.

I need a query which will update `Address` column of `T1` with `New_Address` of `T2`.

I can do it through a loop by checking ID and executing update statement. How can it has to be done with a query?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about

```
UPDATE T1
SET Address = T2.New_Address
FROM T2
WHERE T1.id = T2.id
```

Answer (score 10):

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Address = T2.New_Address
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE T1
SET Address = (select New_Address from T2 where T1.ID=T2.ID );
```

Comment: This - is equivalent to a `LEFT JOIN` and - will also update (setting them to `NULL`) all rows in Table1 that do not have a `NewAdress` in Table2.

Comment: @ypercube - One possible advantage this query does have though is that it will raise an error if there is more than one matching new address rather than silently selecting an undeterministic one. It could be rewritten  as `SET Address = ISNULL((select New_Address from T2 where T1.ID=T2.ID ),Address);` though `MERGE` gives this error checking built in too and would be preferable.